# Maximum reach node in a Graph

Tags: graph

Given a DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph) I want to find the node with maximum reach, or rather, how many nodes can be reached by a single node.
Tried doing BFS by topological order but it doenst work because the sourse might not be the maximum reach source

I couldnt find it but if this has already been asked please redirect me to the correct answer and I'll delete this post.
Thanks

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4258/number-of-reachable-vertices-in-dag-for-every-vertex

Comment: @LiorKogan that post doenst seem to have a useful answer